# Maven UnsupportedClassVersionError while running a build

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, java-5

I set the default JRE to 1.5.0 in the 'Installed JREs" settings in preferences in Eclipse(STS 3.5) and ran a maven build with a profile (which includes the `wsimport` goal of the `jaxws-maven-plugin`). But immediately i get this exception.

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: (org/apache/maven/cli/MavenCli) bad major version at offset=6
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:267)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:151)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:600)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$400(URLClassLoader.java:124)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$ClassFinder.run(URLClassLoader.java:1055)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:274)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:492)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClassFromSelf(ClassRealm.java:389)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:42)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:259)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:242)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:227)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.getMainClass(Launcher.java:144)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:266)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:46)
```

POM.xml(a child POM):

```
<profile>
        <id>retrieve-generate-client</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>

                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.5</source>
                        <target>1.5</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>generate-ordinaryws-client-code</id>
                            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>wsimport</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <packageName>com.abc.service.retrievedocument</packageName>
                        <wsdlDirectory>${basedir}/src/wsdl</wsdlDirectory>
                        <wsdlFiles>
                            <wsdlFile>RetrieveDocument/Technology-RetrieveDocument.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                        </wsdlFiles>
                        <verbose>true</verbose>
                        <sourceDestDir>${project.build.directory}/wsjava/RetrieveDocument</sourceDestDir>

                    </configuration>

                </plugin>
```

But the maven version im using(3.2.1) says it supports java 1.5 and later. What am I missing here? I want to use the JDK 1.5 which i have to run the profile.

Comment: You are compiling with JDK 1.6

Comment: You should use an actuall jdk (version 7 or 8)

Comment: What is the configured Java version in your pom.xml?

Comment: No I purposefully want to run the profile using JDK 1.5 since its a constraint for generating the Web Service client code(production environment which is going to use this code is running at JDK 1.5)

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Its set at 1.7, but I have overridden that parent setting using the maven-compiler-plugin in that profile as you can see. Shouldnt that work?

Comment: Is $JAVA_HOME configured correctly (ie, pointing to Java 1.5 installation)?

Comment: @Jens it's no duplicate. The question is more specific about maven configuration (the basic error that is discussed in the link you shared is understood and not the problem).

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/docs/history.html : Maven 3.2.1 - Required Java Version: Java 6

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Im using maven through Eclipse( have changed the Maven > Installations setting to point to an external maven installation), so JAVA_HOME need not be set is my understanding. Am I correct? And moreover i was bale to run maven before with JDK 1.7 for the same POM.

Comment: As @user158037 points out, your claim that maven 3.2.1 work with Java 5 is wrong. You need at least 6 -- and I would even recommend to use Java 8 (Support for older Java version ended already: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html). However, even if you use JDK 6 (or higher) to run maven, you can still compile your sources to a lower version (so your configuration of `source` and `target` in `maven-compiler-plugin` is ok).

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Yes user158037 is right. I looked it up in maven website only later. Bad documentation on my company's IT inventory department' part :( Spent 2 hours trying to figure out what went wrong. And thanks for the suggestion about the build for lower versions of java :) I will do just that.